# SendGrid cURL response is returning empty but email sends

Tags: curl, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using the below code to send an email via SendGrid. The email sends successfully, but `$response` is always empty. I am trying to get/store the Message ID. I have tried turning SSL on/off, and I've tried my local computer and a production server with SSL.

```
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $sg_data,
      CURLOPT_POST => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Bearer '.getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'),
        'Content-Type: application/json'
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    var_dump($response,curl_error($curl),curl_getinfo($curl));

    curl_close($curl);
```

Again, the email sends, but `var_dump` gives me:

```
string(0) "" string(0) "" array(26) { ["url"]=> string(37) "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(202) ["header_size"]=> int(446) ["request_size"]=> int(520) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0.321982) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(3.8E-5) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.017802) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.070089) ["size_upload"]=> float(306) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(950) ["download_content_length"]=> float(0) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(306) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.321954) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" ["primary_ip"]=> string(13) "167.89.115.21" ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_port"]=> int(443) ["local_ip"]=> string(8) "10.0.1.3" ["local_port"]=> int(60184) }
```

Comment: i have just the same issue here! did u found a solution?